# Read Text File Line by Line, then word by word c++, push on to an array

Tags: c++

My data looks like:

#### numbers.text

```
12     32     21     42

33     566    332    12

66     994    4      33

12     33     33     41
```

and I want to push the first three values on an vector of integers while ignoring the last value.  Every line I need to have a new vector of the first 3 numbers in there. Just spaces are used as separators (a TAB). thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward task.  What exactly have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I think maybe the question is, "WTF am I doing trying to be a programmer when I can't even ask a decent question?"

Comment: @NoahRoberts Patience, patience ...

Comment: What would be the best way to do this. I have tried fscan and gotten into many problems. It is review for exam coming up

Comment: Maybe you shouldnt be so rude, and if you're going to being adding your comment or opinion I would really appreciate you not being a complete jerk. There is no reason for it. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think asking a group of people to do your work for you is the best way to study for an exam?  If you want to study then study.  Do *something* and ask a reasonable question about your attempt to do so.  Otherwise you're simply wasting everyone's time, including yours.

Comment: Well maybe because when I get the answer I actually look as to how I got it... not that I have to explain that to you. I didn't specifically ask for your answer, so if I'm wasting your time then don't answer my questions. It's that simple.

Comment: @JonSmith Not to add oil to the fire, but rather try and explain: when you ask a question there are two important things you must write down: what's the question? **Clearly** and concisely state your question. Second, what have you tried already for coming up with a solution? If we are spending time into writing a proper solution which you have already tried then the result is that both of us wasted our time. We also need to know **you** have put some effort into the issue -- or else why should **we**?

Comment: Well I dont have a problem with what he was trying to say, it's the way he said it. That's just uncalled for. All I'm doing is trying to pass. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ultimately you want to end up with an `std::vector<int>` of 3 integers for each line in the text file.  This is basically an exercise in parsing the file, which is very easy to do using a C++ file stream object along with a stream input iterator.

Use an `std::ifstream` object to open the file.  You can then iterate over each integer in the file using an `std::istream_iterator<int>`.  This will extract each integer, so you can store it in a vector.  If you want to discard the fourth integer on each line, just keep a counter variable handy so that you can discard every 4th value.

And that's basically it.  I'll leave it to you to actually produce the code.

Comment: okay great thanks just looking for ideas, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

1. open the file
2. iterate over each line in the file with `std::getline()`
3. parse the integers out of the line and into a vector

   1. place the line in a `std::istringstream` to parse the integers out
   2. extract three integers from the string stream
   3. push the integers into a vector
   4. what do you want to do with the vector? maybe push that into another vector?

Notice what happened here: You wrote a question, I translated it into a sequence of instructions, and finally you translate that into code. That's how we write simple programs. The trick is in understanding the question well enough to translate it into **pseudocode** as above.

Comment: Agreed thanks very much, the idea is to create a new object with 3 int's in the param being: numberClass(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]).

Answer (score 0):

`std::ifstream` will work if you are just reading the file directly.  If you are using `getline` (which really isn't necessary here), you can write a simple split function to separate the values and insert the ones you want.  Since this sounds like schoolwork, I doubt you'll want to use the `boost::` methods that would make this rather trivial.